# UIResponder Chain Explanation Needed

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uikit, uiresponder, uievent

I'm having trouble getting my `UIButtons`, `UIScrollViews` etc working in this situation:

I have the base `UIViewController`, which is the root controller of the `UIWindow`.
Above that layer I have some other `UIViews` added, which I will call the "Middle Layer View". And on the top I have another `UIView` added for overlay objects.

The Middle Layer View is changed for different views regularly. The `UIView` it uses is from a `UIViewController`, made by a NIB file. Here's an example

```
if ( mode == eModeShowView1 )
    UIViewController* nextController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"View1"...
else if ( mode == eModeShowView2 )
    UIViewController* nextController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"View2"...

[UIView insertSubview:nextController.view below:m_overlayView];
```

Now, when I touch on screen, the first responder is obviously the `OverlayView` or any `UIResponder` on the `OverlayView` that has been touched.
The `UIEvent` of the touch input goes up the view chain but seems to skip the Middle Layer View and the `UIResponders` on that `UIView` altogether. It jumps straight to the root `UIViewController`.

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Could it be solved by somehow creating two `UIEvents`?  One for the Overlay View and one for the Middle Layer View? Is that possible? If so, how?

Any help would be most appreciated.
Thanks,
Rich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit1 start:

you can put a UITapGestureRecognizer to the m_overlayView and initWithTarget:your-middleview action:some-method-in-middleview

Now, in your middleview you can identify recognizer.state as UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan, Ended etc and do what you want to do.

edit1 end:

You can debug it. Just use the logs in `touchesbegan` in all your controllers. It will be clear by logs the sequence of touch responses.

Ok.. so this description of method from documentation might answer you. Your `m_overlayView` and `nextController.view` are regarding each other as siblings and not superview. So your touch on either of them will not be reported to the other but instead to the base `superview` which is a common `superview` to both the siblings.

Hence you are getting that the middle layer is being bypassed. Actually your middle-layer is a sibling and no more a superview. Hope that at least gives you some way ahead ;)

```
insertSubview:belowSubview:
```

Inserts a view below another view in the view hierarchy.

```
(void)insertSubview:(UIView *)view belowSubview:(UIView *)siblingSubview
```

**Parameters**:

```
view
```

The view to insert below another view. It’s removed from its `superview` if it’s not a sibling of siblingSubview.

**siblingSubview**:

The sibling view that will be above the inserted view.

**Discussion**:

This method retains view and sets its next responder to the receiver, which is its new `superview`.

Views can have only one superview. If view already has a `superview` and that view is not the receiver, this method removes the previous `superview` before making the receiver its new `superview`.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the quick response.  I have logged the touchesBegan etc in all my ViewController.  This is how I was able to find out that it is skipping my middle layer.  I've just got no idea why :s.

Comment: Ah yes. That is what is happening.  Does anyone know how I can get around this issue?  Could I insert the middle layer below the overlay and then set the overlay's superview to be the middle layer?